# Como envio un valor obtenido a store, sin usar created()

Tags: vue.js

Quiero pasar un array obtenido en un componente al store de vue, el cual sea dinámico. Ya use **created** pero ese no es dinámico.

quiero que pasajeros obtenga los valores que viene del componet

```
state: {
    pasajeros: []
},
mutations: {
    agregarPasajeros(state, p) {
        state.pasajeros = p;
    }
},
actions: {
    actionAgregarPasajeros({ commit }, p) {
        commit('agregarPasajeros', p);
    }
}
```

este es mi template el cual al dar click se agrega en el array

```
<div class="silla" v-for="item in 8" :key="item.id">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="silla" :value="`${item}`">
</div>
```

Este es el js del template

```
data() {
    return {
        silla: [],
    }
},
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['actionAgregarPasajeros'])
}
```

la idea es que lo que esta en el array silla, lo pueda enviar al *store* y poder reutilizarlo en otros template,
No por medio de props
Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No termino de entender tu problema.. el array no pasa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Qué tal? Podría usar [Setter Computado](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Setter-Computado). Le permitirá obtener datos parciales del estado reutilizables en los componentes, o sea, se vuelve a enviar cuando el estado cambia de valor.

Store:

```
 state: {
    pasajeros: []
 },
  mutations:{
     UpdatePasajero(state, payload) {
        state.pasajeros = payload
     }
  }
```

Componente:

```
<div class="silla">
   <div class="silla" v-for="item in 8" :key="item.id">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="silla" :value="`${item}`">
        {{silla}} // Estado pasajeros: Puede ver aquí la demostración enseguida al dar click en los checkbox
    </div>
</div>

computed: {
    silla: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.pasajeros
      },
      set(newPasajero) {
        this.$store.commit('UpdatePasajero', newPasajero)
      }
    }
  }
```

**GET:** Recupera el valor del estado (pasajeros)

**SET:** Tendrá el nuevo valor cada vez que se asigne un nuevo valor a la propiedad calculada y actualizara el estado.

En lugar de usar una propiedad en el objeto *data()*, se crea una propiedad calculada, obteniendo su estado: `pasajeros` y actualizándola usando las mutaciones en vuex. Finalmente la nueva propiedad calculada `silla` puede usarse en v-model u otro componente.

Si quisiera ver su estado en otro componente al mismo tiempo que usa los checks, solo siga:

```
<template>
   <div>{{pasajeros}}</div>
</template>

import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed:{
     ...mapState(['pasajeros'])
  }
}
```